# Like box and like button not showing on Chrome (win 7 and MacosX) and Safari

Tags: google-chrome, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

Both work fine in Firefox

The site is http://tryalloutdoor.co.uk/

I compared source of pages (for BF like box).
FF gives:

```
 <div class="fb-like-box fb_iframe_widget " data-header="true" data-stream="false" data-border-color="#cccccc" data-show-faces="true" data-height="320" data-width="200" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/connexions-ltd/126573034113963">
```

while Chrome's source says:

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/connexions-ltd/126573034113963" data-width="200" data-height="320" data-show-faces="true" data-border-color="#cccccc" data-stream="false" data-header="true"></div>
```

In Chrome when using Dev tools element shows

"div.fb-like-box 200pxx0px"

similarly

"div.fb-like 710pxx0px"

Any suggestions?

Cmon guys,
Please help me. Is my question so easy or so stupid that no one would give an advice?

Comment: im having the same problem,  it worked about a week ago but now its gone

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your html tag to:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Comment: Thanks @sudsiv,
This was useful to add but unfortunately didn't help me solve the mystery. You can now see pages with it but still no luck.

Comment: I'm just going to use the iframe version for the Like Button for the time being. Problem with it is that it does not allow me pass the correct dynamic URL for each page of the site.